# i keep having these errors when i'm trying to build my project in react native expo and i really need help on how to fix it

Tags: react-native, expo

i ran the "eas build -p android --profile preview" to build my project and i got these errors"× Build failed
 Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" (https://expo.dev/accounts/jesse123gfj/projects/Heifer-Naija-Unlock/builds/462740b5-cd7e-4b55-8be4-6833f0f4fc0f#run-gradlew) phase for more information."

i was expecting my project to build to andriod apk when i run these command"eas build -p android --profile preview"

Comment: Migrate to Flutter, react-native is at version 0.x since years. Also, your link does not give us permission to see, include logs/file into your question.

Answer (score 0):

in the `Terminal` in the root of your project, could you try the following command and see what happens

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
```

If you have an android folder of course.